# HTTP Request in C

Tags: c, http, post, get, winsock2

i'm coding a http request library for a project. I'm using winsock2's sockets to create http requests and i don't know what i'm doing wrong. There is not much on google about http requests in c so i thought i'd ask here.

This is a simple **GET** request function that connects to the server, sends a **GET** request and receives response.

**BTW** I learnt that i shouldn't use **sprintf** cause its unsafe and can cause buffer overflows, what should i use instead that still makes me do the same "***string-formatting***"?

```
char* httpGet(char* host, int port, char* path) {

    char request[1024];
    char response[1024];

    int res;

    SOCKET client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    struct sockaddr_in address;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host);
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(port);
    sprintf(request, "GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n", path, host);
    
    res = connect(client, (struct sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(address));

    if (res == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(client);
        return NULL;
    }

    res = send(client, request, sizeof(request), 0);
    
    if (res == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(client);
        return NULL;
    }

    res = recv(client, response, sizeof(response), 0);

    closesocket(client);

    return response;
}
```

The fact is that i'm getting this response and tbh i don't really know if i'm doing this correctly.

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK                                                                                               Server: Werkzeug/2.2.2 Python/3.11.4                                                                                    Date: Tue, 02 Jan 2024 20:04:58 GMT                                                                                     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8                                                                                  Content-Length: 3                                                                                                       Connection: close                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠        ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠                                            Ê¨⌂`

Comment: You can't return a local array from a function. And `recv()` doesn't return a null-terminated string, so you can't use string operations like `%s` in `sprintf()`.

Comment: Hi @Barmar thanks for replying, how should i do it then? And i'm not using sprintf() with recv(), but correct me if i didn't understand ur comment.

Comment: See the linked question, it explains how to return an array from a function, using dynamic memory allocation. You'll also need to return the length that `recv()` returned.

Comment: Note that there's no reason to expect the entire response to be returned in a single call to `recv()`. What if the web page is more than 1K bytes?